# Letters from numbers code improvement in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and i am having a hard time with this issue : i have a column with number up to 15 that i need to convert to letters, checking the forum i found a fonction N2L fonction, but i need it to do it from VBA becaue others cells formulas relie on this column input so i can't use char etc...
I did a newbie code that works but it is very very ugly.
Could you guys give a me hand, all help would be me much appreciated.
Here is what i did.

```
For Each cellule In Range("D24:D58")
Select Case (cellule)
    Case Is = 1
cellule.Value = "A"
End Select
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("D24:D58")
Select Case (cellule)
    Case Is = 2
cellule.Value = "B"
End Select
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("D24:D58")
Select Case (cellule)
    Case Is = 3
cellule.Value = "C"
End Select
Next cellule
```

and so on until 15 ...
(I have declared cellule as range at the beginning of the sub)
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Could it go beyond 26? It gets a lot more complicated when you move to double letters.

Comment: Rather than finding the column letter just use [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells).  `Cells(2,1)` is A2, `Range(cells(2,1),Cells(3,4))` is A2:D3.  Not sure what your actual case is, but easier to leave the number as a number.

Comment: Was going to post an answer.... but as @BigBen pointed out there's already an answer.  I'd use the one given by ashleedawg (or any that use SPLIT).

Comment: Thank you so much for you feedback. In my  case i just need 1 to 26 no need to go beyond. And to be clear this is not related to column this is for accounting i have number in one column that need to be associated with their number. 1=A,2=B,C=3 and so on.